# MS Access runtime error 3464

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am working on a database for my work and i'm trying to insert and update values from tables with sql inside the vb editor
This is my code:

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Übernehmen_Click()
    Dim strSQL1 As String
    Dim strSQL2 As String
    Dim strSQL3 As String
    Dim ArtikelNr As Integer
    Dim Stück As Integer
    Dim Lieferant As String
    Dim Bestellnr As Integer
    Dim EkPreis As String
    Dim Mwst As String
    Dim Einkaufsort As String
    Dim GhIndex As String
    Dim Datum As String
    Dim Uhrzeit As String
    Dim Lager As String
    Dim Beschreibung As String

    ArtikelNr = [Forms]![Einkauf]![ArtikelNr].Value
    Stück = [Forms]![Einkauf]![Stück].Value
    Lieferant = [Forms]![Einkauf]![Lieferant].Value
    Bestellnr = [Forms]![Einkauf]![Bestellnr].Value
    EkPreis = [Forms]![Einkauf]![EK-Preis].Value
    Mwst = [Forms]![Einkauf]![Mwst-Satz].Value
    Einkaufsort = [Forms]![Einkauf]![Einkaufsort].Value
    GhIndex = [Forms]![Einkauf]![GH-Index].Value
    Datum = [Forms]![Einkauf]![Datum].Value
    Uhrzeit = [Forms]![Einkauf]![Uhrzeit].Value
    Lager = [Forms]![Einkauf]![Lager].Value

    strSQL1 = "INSERT INTO Einkäufe (ArtikelNr, Stück, Lieferant, Bestellnr, EKPreis, MwstSatz, Einkaufsort, GHIndex) VALUES (" & ArtikelNr & "," & Stück & ",'" & Lieferant & "','" & Bestellnr & "','" & EkPreis & "','" & Mwst & "','" & Einkaufsort & "','" & GhIndex & "');"

    Beschreibung = DLast("EinkaufID", "Einkäufe")

    strSQL2 = "INSERT INTO Transaktionen VALUES ('" & ArtikelNr & "','" & Datum & "','" & Lager & "','" & Stück & "','EinkaufID ' + '" & Beschreibung & "' ,'Einkauf',NULL,NULL,'" & Uhrzeit & "');"
    strSQL3 = "UPDATE Lagerbestand SET Stück = Stück+" & Stück & " WHERE ArtikelNr = '" & ArtikelNr & "' AND Lager = '" & Lager & "';"

    DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL1
    DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL2
    DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL3

End Sub
```

After trying to press the button it first adds the two entries and stops at the third one just to throw an error saying "Runtime Error: 3464".
After I press debug it marks the line `DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL3`.

I would appreciate any answer I get.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `Debug.Print strSQL3` to output the text from the troublesome `UPDATE` statement to the Immediate window.  Copy that text and paste it into your question.

Comment: `ArtikelNr` sounds like it's shortened German for Article Number.. is that correct? If the data type of this field is a number then you should probably remove those single quotes when matching it to a field. Like this `" WHERE ArtikelNr =" & ArtikelNr & " AND Lager ='" & Lager & "';"`

Comment: Yes it is, but shouldn't it cast it back to an Integer?

Comment: Okay, apparently it does cast back if you use the parameter to create a new data entry but if you want to compare it it does not cast it back. sql just sees an integer and a string an cant compare them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My error was trying to compare an integer with a string. Even though sql does cast it from an integer to a string if you make a new entry, it does not cast it if you want to compare in a where.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google of "Runtime Error 3464" suggests this is a data type mismatch. You'll typically see this when you try to save a date value in a string field or something like that.

Double check the types passed to your SQL statements match the columns they should be saved to - and apply any necessary conversions if you spot differences.

Also one final heads up...by building your SQL string dynamically you are leaving yourself vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks - you should consider using ADOCommands with parameters.

Comment: Yeah, i know what that error stands for. My problem is why it is happening. 

About that SQL Injection, i dont know how to do ADOCommands. I just started to use Access so i'm not that familier with it.

Comment: To answer that I'd need to know the structure (data types etc.) of your table and to see the SQL that gets generated by your sql. But then, if you have that, you should probably be able to figure out by yourself.

Comment: The datatypes are similar to those used for the variables. I can't give you further information until i'm at work again. I only work there on fridays and this friday i cant.

Comment: In strSQL2 you have Stuck and ArtikelNr wrapped in single quotes but they are defined as integers. Could be that...

Comment: Yeah but it automatically casts it back to an Integer so thats not the problem, especially if the first two commands work without problems because they add the data into the table without an error. its just strSQL3 which makes problems.

Comment: Does it definitely cast back to an integer - as I said it's been a while. Without getting my hands on the Database, here's what I would suggest: print out the value in `strSQL3`. This will be something like `UPDATE Lagerbestand SET Stück = Stück+6 WHERE ArtikelNr = '3' AND Lager = 'some value';`. Try to run this in standalone (in a copy of your database) and if that does not work try again with no `WHERE` condition. If that works try adding the `WHERE` conditions one at a time and running again to identify which part of the statement is causing the problem.

Comment: Okay, i got it. Apparently if you use an integer to create a new entry sql does not care if you give it the number as an integer or a string, but if you want to compare it in a where it has to be an integer. That was the error.