# How to fix '3464' on 'Update' sql function in vba

Tags: vba, ms-access

Im trying to modiffy the records in a table using a "Update" method in a button (If anyone knows a better way of doing this i will hear it), but when i click the button i get a '3464' error

i think that the problem is a date() value but i have already turned it into a string i have also moved the ' and " to another position trying to correct the code but nothing

```
Dim strSQL As String
Set dbs = CurrentDb()
Dim fca As String
fca = Date

strSQL = "UPDATE Herramientas" & " SET Inventario = '" & y & "' ,Quien_solicita = '" & Me.lblusr.Caption & "' ,Fecha_Salida = '" & fca & "' WHERE Id = ' " & Me.txt_id & "';"

CurrentDb.Execute strSQL

Me.lst_hrm.Requery
```

i want to update the records in a table but i get this error idk how to fix it help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MS Access runtime error 3464](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30806890/ms-access-runtime-error-3464)

Comment: mysql or ms/access??

Comment: **WARNING**: This code has a number of [SQL injection bugs](https://bobby-tables.com) caused by introducing unescaped data into the query. Use placeholder values instead of using string concatenation.

Comment: i dont think this is a duplicated, the error in the refered post might be the same but happended outside of the SQL statement and it cause was a comparision betwen 2 variables of diferent type

Comment: Why turn the date into a string? If Fecha_Salida is a date/time field, use # delimiter instead of apostrophe. If ID is a number field, don't use any delimiter. Why are you saving a label caption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use *Date()* and no quotes on numbers:

```
Dim strSQL As String
Set dbs = CurrentDb()

strSQL = "UPDATE Herramientas SET Inventario = " & y & ", Quien_solicita = '" & Me.lblusr.Caption & "', Fecha_Salida = Date() WHERE Id = " & Me.txt_id & ";"

CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
```

Comment: Thank you! you saved my life, i tried converting the date to a string cause i thought that was the problem, but i see that it wasn`t that, so if it`s a number then i dont use quotes ('')?

Comment: Great! Then please mark as answered. And right: No quotes around numbers.